# encrypted fields

Tags: 7, entities, services

I am using Services to collect data from an application.
I will store each user's key on their drupal profile, and want to match that key against a key  submitted through services. 
I would like to store the user key as an encrypted field on the user's profile, then match that to the one being submitted.
I'm looking for a contrib module that provides:

- field encryption
- a simple way to match (yes/no) the encrypted field against another entity

Any suggestions?

The closest I've found so far is http://drupal.org/project/encrypt

Comment: It sounds like you need OAuth authentication. The user account can have it's own authorization keys.

Answer (score 2):

Look into [Encrypted Settings Field](http://drupal.org/project/encset) to store your field.

> This module adds the "encrypted settings" field through Field API,
>   which has the following two features:
>
> The field can be encrypted before saving to the database
>
> The field can be validated to follow INI format.
>
> This module is ideal to save credential settings information,
>   such as a "Credit Card" field to add
>   to users' profile.

You will likely not find a module that relates and verifies this against another field ... that business logic specific to your application.